# SVG code stops pages from loading in ios browsers and Safari on Macs

Tags: ios, angular, svg, safari

I built a website with Angular 16 and after launching it discovered some pages won't load in Chrome or Safari on my iphone.  I have a couple friends with macs who tested it and it works fine in macs version of Chrome but does the same thing in Safari that happens on my phone.

After commenting out several things until the pages load and slowly adding things until the problem came back I narrowed it down to a simple SVG arrow I'm using in a number input component I created.  The thing that really confuses me is I use it in my sidebar component as well which toggles in and out when a burger icon is clicked.

To keep everything as minimal as possible I define all my SVG elements as `<symbol>`s and use them with the `<use>` tag throughout my code.  The way I have it defined in my `index.html` file goes as follows.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
style="display: none;">

    <defs>
    
        <symbol id="dropdown_arrow" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
            <polygon points="0,10 10,5 0,0 "/>
        </symbol>

    </defs>
</svg>
```

Then in my component I use it like this.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" width="33%" height="33%" class="incrementArrow">

    <use
      href="#dropdown_arrow"
      transform-origin="5 5"
      transform="rotate(-90)"
      fill="hsl(var(--gray-100), 1)"
    />

</svg>
```

The `incrementArrow` class is simply

```
.incramentArrow{
    grid-area: 1/1/2/2;
}
```

When I comment out the `<svg>` tag everything works.  It seems like if I just add a blank `<svg>` tag without any properties defined the problem comes back.  The only SVGs I use on the site is this arrow, a simple "x" that serves as a close button on the sidebar, the burger menu, my logo and the github logo.  I do all my own graphics so I manually make sure there's as few anchor points as absolutely necessary, I made every part of the logo into their own symbols and join them together into 2 other symbols for the portrait and landscape versions.  I got the github logo from their press kit so I'm guessing that's optimal in terms of the number of anchor points used, so I don't have a ton o artwork all over the site.  I created a pattern in my footer out of the logo's icon using the `<use>` tag and that's all the SVG I use on the entire site.

Does anybody know what could be causing this to happen in ios and safari on mac?  I also viewed the site on a couple android phones and it works perfectly fine on those.  What is the problem here?

Comment: What if you use xlink:href rather than just href?

Comment: @RobertLongson idk.  I use `href` on my other `<use>` tags and they work perfectly fine.  I was just tinkering with it adding properties 1 by 1 to the svg tag and noticed when I have `<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" width="33%"></svg>` the pages that use that number input will load.  But when I add the height which is `<svg vewBox="0 0 10 10" width="33%" height="33%"></svg>"` it goes back to freezing up.  So I don't even get to a point of being able to add the `<use>` tag to it before the problem occurs.

Comment: you can report webkit bugs [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/)

Comment: Might not fix your issue, but worth trying to uncover the real cause: set height in various formats, from your original percentages, through pixels, em, vh, whatever you can think of.